# From mp3 to wav and back to mp3. What's the best method for loosing the less quality possible?

Tags: audio, file-conversion

Supposing that you have to enhance and clean up an mp3 file. After the clean up you export the file in wav format and you import the file to a DAW to make a final mastering.
Then you export the mastered file in wav format.
Client wants the file to be delivered in mp3 so you must reconvert the wav file to mp3.

Supposing that we use a sr of 44.1KHZ for the wav file, what's the best bit rate that you must export the wav file in order to have the less loss in sound quality when the delivered file will be converted to mp3? And do we should applied any dithering considering the final mp3 conversion?

Answer (score 0):

a] ask the client for wav original

b] compress output to higher bitrate mp3 than the original, though that doesn't guarantee anything. also if you work in 24bit, you can save as mp3 without dithering, it doesn't need it.

Comment: Client wants mp3 for streaming reasons (not heavy) so even 320kbs is a lot for an easy web streaming of 30 minutes audio. For example standard audiobook bit rate as you may know is mp3 192kbs. I dared to send him a 256kbs file. Last info about dithering was helpful if it's wright.